# How to get resource logical id cloudformation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to get a resource's logical ID inside itself like we do with `"Ref" : "logicalName"`. I just want to get the resource logical id (here Instance1) in its own properties section dynamically. Till now i have to hard code resource name.

```
{
  "AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
    "Mappings": {
        "Para" : {
          "Layer"     : { "Instance1" : "Testing", "Instance2" : "Staging", "Instance3" : "Production" }
        }
    },  
    "Resources": {
        "Instance1": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-5fb8c835",
            "Tags": [
              { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "Para", "Name", "Instance1" ]} }
                ]
            }
        },
        "Instance2": {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "Properties": {
            "ImageId": "ami-5fb8c835",
            "Tags": [
              { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::FindInMap" : [ "Para", "Name", "Instance2" ]} }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

I just want to get resource name (eg Instance1 or instance 2) in key, value tag lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to retrieve the logical name itself within a custom tag, but CloudFormation does automatically tag every Instance with an `aws:cloudformation:logical-id` tag.

> In addition to any tags you define, AWS CloudFormation automatically
>   creates the following stack-level tags with the prefix aws::
>
> - aws:cloudformation:logical-id
> - aws:cloudformation:stack-id
> - aws:cloudformation:stack-name

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-resource-tags.html

Comment: Not sure if this is true at this time. I do not see any tags with 'aws:cloudformation:logical-id' inside my stack